# Could not load type "fos_user_change_password_form" + FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have followed the instructions on `FOSUserBundle` installation. I'm using Symfony 2.0 and `FOSUserBundle` locked to 1.2.0. When I'm trying to access `profile.change-password`, I'm getting an error like

> Could not load type "fos_user_change_password_form"

```
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\FormException: Could not load type "fos_user_change_password_form" (uncaught exception) at /vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php line 383
```

In `config.yml` file I have:

```
change_password:
    form:
        type:               fos_user_change_password
        handler:            fos_user.change_password.form.handler.default
        name:               fos_user_change_password_form
        validation_groups:  [ChangePassword]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all because of version problem.since I'm using number of bundles it should match each others versions. `FOSUserBundle` should have version 1.2.4. for `symfony 2.0.16`